# Trying to count first 2 words of a word document in C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, word-count

I am making a program that will count some variables of a word document and upload these into my program, using MVC.

I have managed to count the amount of words in the document, and also "key words" which I have defined above.

However I am now having problems with implementing how to display the first 2 words of the document in the program.

Below is my current code, how would I go about adding the first two words in?

```
for (var i = 1; i <= document.Words.Count; i++)
{
    if (Regex.Match(document.Words[i].Text.TrimEnd(), @"\w+").Success)
        count++;
    if (keywords.Contains(document.Words[i].Text.ToUpper().TrimEnd()))
        keyWordCount++;
```

Comment: Don't all words returned by `document.Words` match `\w`?

Answer (score 1):

Be careful as document might not contain any word.  Use if check as appropriate.

```
foreach(var word in document.Words.Take(2))
{
    //yay, got two words!
}
```

Comment: Hi, I don't seem to have the "Words.Take" functionality, is there a missing reference library somewhere?

Comment: @cg529d I think you have to include 'System.Linq' namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why all those verification stuff, but focusing in the two first words, this can work.

```
string[] twoWords;
if (document.Words.Count > 1)
{
   string words = document.Words[0].Text + " " + document.Words[1].Text;
   twoWords = words.Split(' ');    
}
```